# Creating style for Frame in MS Blend

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend, windows-phone-8

How to create a style for PhoneApplicationFrame in MS Blend using the same way as for any control, i.e. 
`[RightClick] -> [Edit Style] -> [Edit a Copy...]` ?
I need to edit it with design view and not only from code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

- Create in Resource section

`<Style TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame" x:Key="MyFrame"></Style>`

- Open Resources tab (mostly on the right side of window)
- Find MyFrame in the list and click on the icon

And you will see a frame in a designer.

**Notes:**

(The Resource section may be: `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>` in the page 
or `<Application.Resources>` in App.xaml  or `<ResourceDictionary>` in dictionary file)

(You may need to add a namespace 
`xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"`)